# action bar menu in all the activitis

Tags: android, android-activity

I am a beginner android programmer ... I want to do something simple:

can I use these function and show my action bar in all the activities without copy these function in every activity's file?

thank you for help

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);


    return true;
} 

@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // action with ID action_refresh was selected
    case R.id.item1:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity3.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
      break;
    // action with ID action_settings was selected
    case R.id.item4:
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity4.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
      break;
    case R.id.item5:
        Intent intent4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Bmicalc.class);
        startActivity(intent4);
      break;
    case R.id.item6:
        Intent intent5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity5.class);
        startActivity(intent5);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep these in a parent activity class and extend it inside all your activities instead of extending `Activity`

Keep a parent activity which has these 2 common methods.

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
return true;
} 

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
// action with ID action_refresh was selected
case R.id.item1:
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity3.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
  break;
// action with ID action_settings was selected
case R.id.item4:
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity4.class);
    startActivity(intent3);
  break;
case R.id.item5:
    Intent intent4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Bmicalc.class);
    startActivity(intent4);
  break;
case R.id.item6:
    Intent intent5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity5.class);
    startActivity(intent5);
  break;
default:
  break;
}

return true;
} 
}
```

Extend the parent class in your activity.

```
public class YourActivity extends ParentActivity {


}
```

Comment: how ? sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: rather than lets say having activity 2 extend Activity. Have it extend activity 1(one with the action bar items)

Comment: the action bar is already in "Activity" ...  and the other class extend activity